# Translating a number to a string and returning all possible permutations

Tags: javascript

I was watching a live [mock interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=057Rs6CgJnY&feature=youtu.be&t=38m49s) and this question came up:

The problem states that given a number, for example `12258`. Translate it to a string given that each number is associated with a letter `1=a, 2=b...z=26`. Also, find all the possible translations of the number. For example:

`'1,2,2,5,8' = aabeh 
 '12,2,5,8 = lbeh
 '1,22,5,8' = avbeh ...etc.`

I was able to take the number and translate to the string `aabeh` quite easily as shown in this snippet:

```js
var num = 12258;

var dict = {
  1: "a",
  2: "b",
  3: "c",
  4: "d",
  5: "e",
  6: "f",
  7: "g",
  8: "h",
  9: "i",
  10: "j",
  11: "k",
  12: "l",
  13: "m",
  14: "n",
  15: "o",
  16: "p",
  17: "q",
  18: "r",
  19: "s",
  20: "t",
  21: "u",
  22: "v",
  23: "w",
  24: "x",
  25: "y",
  26: "z"
}

function translate(n) {
  n = String(n).split('').map((el, i, arr) => {
    return dict[el]
  }).join('')

  return n;

}

console.log(translate(num));
```

However, I'm struggling to create a function that creates the various permutations of the number.

My initial thought process was to find all of possible combinations of 2 digit numbers < 26.

```
function translateMult(n) {
    var initArr = String(n).split('');

    var possibleCombo = initArr.map((el,i,arr)=>{
        if(parseInt(arr[i-1] + arr[i]) < 26){
            arr.push(arr[i-1] + arr[i]);
       }
       return arr;
    }); 

    return possibleCombo
}
```

This creates 5 arrays that include `[ '1', '2', '2', '5', '8', '12', '22', '25' ]`. I believe I need to check each number in the `initArr` of `['1', '2', '2', '5', '8']` and if say `1+2 === 12 && < 26` return `12`, but then remove `1,2`. But I having trouble wrapping my head around how to do it.

I also had tried just a `for loop` as I thought that might jog something loose in my thinking...

```
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(parseInt(arr[i-1] + arr[i]) < 26){
    arr.push(arr[i-1] + arr[i]);
  } 
}
```

But again that just gives me a single array with all the numbers possible number combos. I'm obviously missing a next step in the logic. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a clear cut [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem. The conceptual answer is to build a tree, initializing it with a branch consisting of the first digit. Then for each consecutive digit, you:

1. Fork each branch such that the last digit and the new digit can form a new translation (`lastDigit*10 + digit <= 26`).
2. Append the digit to every branch (excluding new ones from step 1).

Here's a function that generates each translation:

```
function translations( number ) {

    // Convert our number into an array of digits
    const digits = number.toString().split( "" ).map( digit => parseInt( digit ) );

    // Initialize our tree with a single sequence of the first digit
    const translations = [[ digits[ 0 ] ]];

    // Loop through remaining digits
    for ( let i = 1; i < digits.length; i ++ ) {

        // Loop through translations; don't include ones we add on this step
        const length = translations.length;
        for ( let n = 0; n < length; n ++ ) {

            // Fork the translation if lastDigit * 10 + currentDigit is within our range
            const sum = translations[ n ][ translations[ n ].length - 1 ] * 10 + digits[ i ];
            if ( sum <= 26 ) translations.push( [ ...translations[ n ].slice( 0, - 1 ), sum ] );

            // Append currentDigit to the translation
            translations[ n ].push( digits[ i ] );

        }

    }

    const values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return translations.map( translation => translation.map( key => values[ key - 1 ] ).join( "" ) );

}
```

If you want just the count, your translations array can be an array of numbers that represent the last value of each branch.

Comment: should that be `if ( sum <= 26 )` ?